# conditional formatting in rails partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I am rendering a rails partial and I want to alternate the background color when it renders the partial.  I know that is not super clear so here is an example of what I want to do:

Row One grey Background


Row Two yellow background


Row Three grey Background


Row Four yellow background

- sorry stackoverflow seams to prevent the background colors from being shown but I think this makes my idea clear

This is the view code that I am using

```
<table>
  <%= render :partial => 'row' :collection => @rows %>
</table>
```

the _row.html.erb partial looks like this

```
<tr bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
  <td><%= row.name %></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is I do not know how to change the background color for every other row.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the Cycle helper. Something like this:

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>">
  <td><%= row.name %></td>
</tr>
```

Or in your case use bgcolor instead, although i would recomend using css classes.

You can cycle through more than two values: cycle(‘first’, ‘second’, ‘third’, ‘and_more’).

There is also: reset_cycle(‘cycle_name’) This makes sure that on each iteration, you will start again with your first value of the cycle list.

Check the rails [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle) for more examples.

Comment: If you use multiple lists or tables on a page, I recommend naming your cycles.  Just pass :name => 'some_unique_name' to the end of the cycle('a', 'b', ...) call.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, you can use javascript to change the element's style based on (total number of TD's % 2).

That way all your visual stuff are contained in html/css/javascript layer. Then again, this technique does not work if javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There is one "gotcha" with cycle: If you should append to the string, the cycle breaks. For example,

```
cycle('odd', 'even') << " some other classes"
```

will break the cycle. However, reversing the order or constructing a string works fine:

```
"some other classes " << cycle('odd', 'even')
"#{cycle('odd', 'even')} some other classes"
```

I've not (yet) delved into the source to see why this may be so. Also, I'm using Rails 3.2.x